# Unable to access redux state and actions inside nested component in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a NoteItem component and it is recursively rendering itself from an array inside itself, But at the topmost component when I use redux functions at the top level parent NoteItem I'm able to use the actions and access the state but inside the nested NoteItem component when I try to use it, It is giving it as undefined, I thought we can use redux wherever we want to use it and access the state and functions as well

This is the parent Sidebar component

Sidebar.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Popover, Tooltip } from "antd";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import "./sidebar.css";

import settingsIcon from "../icons/settings.svg";

import addIcon from "../icons/plus.svg";

import NoteItem from "../NoteItem/NoteItem";
import { getNotes, createNote } from "../actions/noteActions";
import store from "../store";
import { SET_CONTEXTMENU_VISIBLE, SET_ACTIVE_NOTE } from "../actions/types";

class Sidebar extends Component {
  state = {
    notes: this.props.notes,
    ownUpdate: false,
    xPos: 0,
    yPos: 0,
    mouseDownOnMenu: this.props.mouseDownOnMenu,
    contextMenuVisible: this.props.contextMenuVisible,
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (state.ownUpdate) {
      return {
        ...state,
        ownUpdate: false,
      };
    } else {
      if (props.notes != state.notes) {
        return {
          notes: props.notes,
        };
      }
      if (props.contextMenuVisible != state.contextMenuVisible) {
        return {
          contextMenuVisible: props.contextMenuVisible,
        };
      }
      if (props.mouseDownOnMenu != state.mouseDownOnMenu) {
        return {
          mouseDownOnMenu: props.mouseDownOnMenu,
        };
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  addNote = () => {
    const newNote = {
      name: "Untitled",
    };

    this.props.createNote(newNote);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
      const { mouseDownOnMenu } = this.state;
      if (mouseDownOnMenu) {
        return;
      }
      store.dispatch({
        type: SET_CONTEXTMENU_VISIBLE,
        payload: false,
      });
      store.dispatch({
        type: SET_ACTIVE_NOTE,
        payload: undefined,
      });
    });

    this.props.getNotes();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousedown", window);
  }

  addSubNote = (note, path) => {
    this.props.addSubNote(note, path);
  };

  setMouseDownActive = () => {
    this.setState({
      mouseDownOnMenu: !this.state.mouseDownOnMenu,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { notes, contextMenuVisible, xPos, yPos } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="sidebar-container">
        <div className="header-container">
          <h4>Username</h4>
          <Tooltip title="Settings" placement="right">
            <img src={settingsIcon} />
          </Tooltip>
        </div>

        <div className="sidebar-content-container">
          <div className="sidebar-controls-container">
            <h4>Notes</h4>
            <div className="add-icon-button" onClick={this.addNote}>
              <img src={addIcon} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="sidebar-page-container">
            {notes &&
              notes.map((note, index) => (
                <NoteItem note={note} key={note._id}></NoteItem> // I can use all the functions and 
 // access the state in these components
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    notes: state.note.notes,
    contextMenuVisible: state.note.contextMenuVisible,
    mouseDownOnMenu: state.note.mouseDownOnMenu,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    createNote: (noteData) => dispatch(createNote(noteData)),
    getNotes: () => dispatch(getNotes()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Sidebar);
```

This is my NoteItem component

NoteItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./noteitem.css";
import pageIcon from "../icons/file-text.svg";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

import addIcon from "../icons/plus.svg";
import caretIcon from "../icons/play.svg";

import { Popover, Button, Input, Menu } from "antd";
import { addSubNote, deleteNote } from "../actions/noteActions";
import { DeleteOutlined, EditOutlined, LinkOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import {
  SET_ACTIVE_NOTE,
  SET_CONTEXTMENU_VISIBLE,
  SET_MOUSEDOWNON_MENU,
} from "../actions/types";
import axios from "axios";
import apiUrl from "../utils/getApiUrl";
import store from "../store";

class NoteItem extends Component {
  state = {
    subNoteOpen: false,
    contextMenuVisible: this.props.contextMenuVisible,
    xPos: 0,
    yPos: 0,
    deleteNoteActive: false,
    renamePopupVisible: false,
    note: this.props.note,
    ownUpdate: false,
    activeNote: this.props.activeNote,
    subNotes: [],
    mouseDownOnMenu: this.props.mouseDownOnMenu,
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snap) {
    if (
      prevProps.activeNote != this.props.activeNote &&
      this.props.activeNote
    ) {
      this.setState({
        activeNote: this.props.activeNote,
        ownUpdate: true,
      });
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (state.ownUpdate) {
      return {
        ...state,
        ownUpdate: false,
      };
    } else {
      if (props.note != state.note) {
        return {
          note: props.note,
        };
      }
      if (props.contextMenuVisible != state.contextMenuVisible) {
        return {
          contextMenuVisible: props.contextMenuVisible,
        };
      }
      if (props.mouseDownOnMenu != state.mouseDownOnMenu) {
        return {
          mouseDownOnMenu: props.mouseDownOnMenu,
        };
      }
      if (props.activeNote != state.activeNote) {
        return {
          activeNote: props.activeNote,
        };
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  getSubNotes = async () => {
    try {
      const { note } = this.state;
      if (note) {
        const subNotes = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/note/sub-notes`, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          params: {
            id: note._id,
          },
        });
        this.setState({
          subNotes: subNotes.data,
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  addNewSubNote = async (note) => {
    try {
      const subNote = await axios.post(
        `${apiUrl}/note/subnote/new`,
        {
          note: {
            name: "Untitled",
          },
          path: note.path,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      this.setState({
        subNotes: [...this.state.subNotes, subNote.data],
        subNoteOpen: true,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  getRenameNoteInput = () => {
    return (
      <div className="rename-note-container">
        <Input placeholder="Enter name" />
        <Button type="primary">Save</Button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  toggleSubNote = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        subNoteOpen: !this.state.subNoteOpen,
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.subNoteOpen) {
          this.getSubNotes();
        }
      }
    );
  };

  toggleContextMenu = (e, note) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var body = document.body,
      html = document.documentElement;
    var height = Math.max(
      body.scrollHeight,
      body.offsetHeight,
      html.clientHeight,
      html.scrollHeight,
      html.offsetHeight
    );
    if (e.pageY > height - 100) {
      this.setState(
        {
          xPos: e.pageX,
          yPos: e.pageY - 130,
        },
        () => {
          store.dispatch({
            type: SET_ACTIVE_NOTE,
            payload: note,
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.setState(
        {
          xPos: e.pageX,
          yPos: e.pageY,
        },
        () => {
          store.dispatch({
            type: SET_ACTIVE_NOTE,
            payload: note,
          });
        }
      );
    }
    store.dispatch({
      type: SET_CONTEXTMENU_VISIBLE,
      payload: true,
    });
  };

  deleteNote = ({ domEvent }) => {
    domEvent.preventDefault();
    store.dispatch({
      type: SET_MOUSEDOWNON_MENU,
      payload: true,
    });
    store.dispatch({
      type: SET_CONTEXTMENU_VISIBLE,
      payload: false,
    });
    const { note } = this.state;
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.deleteNote(note);
  };

  setMouseDownActive = () => {
    store.dispatch({
      type: SET_MOUSEDOWNON_MENU,
      payload: !this.state.mouseDownOnMenu,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      subNoteOpen,
      note,
      renamePopupVisible,
      activeNote,
      subNotes,
      contextMenuVisible,
      xPos,
      yPos,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        {activeNote && contextMenuVisible && activeNote._id == note._id && (
          <div
            className="context-menu"
            style={{ position: "fixed", top: yPos, left: xPos }}
          >
            <Menu
              style={{ width: "200px", borderRadius: "3px" }}
              onMouseDown={this.setMouseDownActive}
              onMouseUp={this.setMouseDownActive}
            >
              <Menu.Item icon={<EditOutlined />}>Rename</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item icon={<LinkOutlined />}>Copy Link</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item icon={<DeleteOutlined />} onClick={this.deleteNote}>
                Delete
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
          </div>
        )}
        <Popover
          content={this.getRenameNoteInput()}
          placement="bottom"
          overlayClassName="no-arrow"
          visible={renamePopupVisible}
        >
          <div
            className={
              activeNote && activeNote._id == note._id
                ? "page-item page-item-active"
                : "page-item"
            }
            onContextMenu={(e) => this.toggleContextMenu(e, note)}
          >
            <img
              src={caretIcon}
              onClick={this.toggleSubNote}
              className={subNoteOpen ? "caret-open" : "caret"}
            />
            <img src={pageIcon} />

            <span>{note.name}</span>
            <div
              className="add-page-button"
              onClick={() => this.addNewSubNote(note)}
            >
              <img src={addIcon} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Popover>
        <div
          className={
            subNoteOpen
              ? "sub-page-container subpage-open"
              : "sub-page-container"
          }
        >
          {subNotes.length > 0 ? (
            <div>
              {subNotes.map((subNote) => (
                <NoteItem note={subNote} key={subNote._id} /> // I can't use any redux functions or 
 // access redux state in these components
              ))}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <p className="empty-text">Empty</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    activeNote: state.note.activeNote,
    contextMenuVisible: state.note.contextMenuVisible,
    mouseDownOnMenu: state.note.mouseDownOnMenu,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addSubNote: (note, path) => dispatch(addSubNote(note, path)),
    deleteNote: (note) => dispatch(deleteNote(note)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NoteItem);
```

Comment: `I try to use it, It is giving it as undefined` Use what and where and what is giving what as undefined? I don't think what you provided is a good minimum reproducible example, looks like 95% of the code is irrelevant to your problem

Comment: When try to use redux, When I try to access state or call actions, I'm getting undefined error, All of the code is here, Only redux code is not here, that is not causing the issue as it is working in parent component

Comment: You have dumped about 300 lines of code, it would be helpful if you could indicate what is undefined and where in the code that you posted.

Comment: everything from the mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps is undefined, and I'm getting ```this.props.deleteNote(note);``` as undefined when I try to call it in deleteNote

Answer (score 1):

Your connected default exported NoteItem component receives the props - but then it is recursively rendering the *unconnected* version of NoteItem. That version has no knowledge of the redux store.

You could do something like

```js
const ConnectedNoteItem = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
class NoteItem extends Component {
// ... use ConnectedNoteItem in here
})
export default ConnectedNoteItem
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still when I try to use this.props.deleteNote, It is giving undefined error inside the nested NoteItem

Comment: You are only providing the props note and key to your nested NoteItem.  You probably want to pass through all of the props of the current NoteItem too? <NoteItem {...this.props} note={subNote} key={subNote._id} /> or maybe manually pass down certain props that don’t come from connect.

Comment: @LindaPaiste In Sidebar.js I'm passing only those 2 props, key, note but I can access them from redux directly inside the component however I can't access them inside the nested one, I tried your solution but it is passing the same note down again and again so the data is getting replicated